# How can I make all markers on a custom Google map appear together instead of being separated by pages?

Tags: google-maps

After a certain number of markers have been added to a custom Google map, Google breaks them into separate pages.  To view any of the latter ones, at the bottom of the marker list one has to click to page two, and then these are viewed separately from all the markers on page 1.  Is there a way to alter the map so they all appear together?  I can't find any documentation on this behavior or any location to change it, such as preferences for how many markers are displayed at a time.